# Remote push notification heads-up not working in react native when app is in background state (Android)

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I have integrated push notification using Firebase library. Below library specifications,

```
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^10.5.0",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
```

When app is in background state push notification is received but it's not pop up on screen.
What setting i need to do to heads-up push notification when app is in background state.

Answer (score 1):

Try using firebase console or postman to send notification, if you still face problem to get notification then your sdk is not setup correctly.for postman use this link
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
and paramenters:

```
    {
       "to" : "your_token",
       "collapse_key" : "type_a",
       "notification" : {
        "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
        "title": "Title of Your Notification"
                    }
    }
```

and headers:

```
      Authorization:server_key
      Content-Type:application/json
```